# C# combobox if statement + continue button incorporation

Tags: c#, combobox, click, selection

This code doesn't work. I don't know what to fix.

```
 public sealed partial class Home : Page
{
    public Home()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ComboBox1.Items.Add("Hindiiiii");

    }

    string selection = null;
    private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex!=1)
        {
            selection = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void Continue(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(selection != null)
        {
            if (selection == "Hindiiiii")
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
            else if (selection == "English")
                this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Home));
        }
    }
```

When a user selects Hindiiiii on the main screen and clicks continues he is not redirected to the next page (MainPage).

Comment: The user selects a language from combobox TranslateFrom. I want to make it so then he can click continue and will be directed to the unique page tied with the language he chose. The button is called Continue which the user clicks to be directed to the next page.

Comment: Are you sure `Continue` is hooked up to your button? Check your XAML code and see if `Click="Continue"` is there.

Comment: yes the property click = continue and the content is also continue.

Comment: What about the combo box. Does it say `SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndex"` in the XAML?

Comment: You might also consider adding a breakpoint right after the if statement in `ComboBox1_SelectedIndex` and checking the value of `selection`.

Comment: No it didn't. Should the code be private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)

or  private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Comment: Yes, yes it should! =) `ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Make sure your XAML includes the event: `<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox1" SelectionChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndex"/>`

Comment: Ok it works!!!! thanks. so why did selectionchanged had to equal combobox1_selectedindex?

Comment: No problem. That's just to register that method for the SelectedIndexChanged event. If you didn't register it for that method, nothing would happen if the user selected another item. This MSDN article might help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh758286.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your main page looks like this:

[image]

You can store the selection in a variable:

```
string selection = null;
private void ComboBox1_SelectedIndex(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex!=-1)
    {
        selection = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }

}
```

Then in your click event you can pass parameters between your pages:

```
private void Continue(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(selection != null)
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage), selection); //send the contents of the variable to another page
}
```

And let's say you had another page with a TextBox and a TextBlock:

In your other pages' `OnNavigatedTo` event, you can retrieve the parameters so you don't have to create a page for every selected language:

```
string selection = null;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    selection = e.Parameter.ToString();
    languageTextBlock.Text = selection; //the textblox is now the selected language

    //decide what the contents are based on the selection
    if (selection == "English")
        translation.Text = "Something in English";
    else if (selection == "Hindi")
        translation.Text = "Something in Hindi";
    else if (selection == "German")
        translation.Text = "Something in German";
    //etc
}
```

When you go to the next page, this allows you to create your page based on the selected item. This image demonstrates this:

[image]

Alternatively, you can solve your problem by creating a page for every possible language:

```
private void Continue(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(selection != null)
    {
        if(selection == "English")
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(EnglishPage));
        else if(selection == "Hindi")
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(HindiPage));
         //and so on
     }
 }
```

I prefer to do it this way because it's a lot simpler.

**Edit**: I see `Items` in the property box but I'm not aware of how to use it to add combo box items. This is the way that I usually see it done:

[image]

Of course you'll need to replace `MainPage` with your page (if it's not already named MainPage).

**Another edit:**

If you added the items via the properties panel, you have to access the `Content`. Use this instead, if you want:

```
string selection = null;
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ComboBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
    {
        //selection = ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
         selection = (ComboBox1.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: hey can u explain how: string selection = null;
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    selection = e.Parameter.ToString();
} is used?

Comment: Sure. It'll take a few minutes. I'll add the explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do I need to create a certain structure in the combobox in order to use combobox1.selecteditem.tostring()? Currently I created "Items" [0] ComboBoxItem, etc.. but the code does not work. I put Hindi in the Content field.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add items to the ComboBox? In your page with the combobox you can do `ComboBox1.Items.Add("language 1")` for every language, instead. You should place this right under `InitializeComponent` in your page's constructor in the code-behind.

Comment: Aha your help is great! I prefer the simpler way as well. But what do u mean when u say I don't have to create a page for every language? I think I would have to anyways. There is unique content tied to each language I want to display. Also, if I'm using VS 2013, can I add items to the combobox a different way? In the properties box maybe?

Comment: By not creating a page for every language, I mean you can use just one other page whose contents are based on the parameter(the string `selection`). In the second screenshot, that's the only page used for the language. If you go back and choose another language and click continue, the page will have a new content based on the selection.

Comment: OK Thanks! Can I assign contents to a parameter if the content is a bunch of buttons?

Comment: Are the buttons going to be used to select the language?

Comment: Only on the main page. OK the code is still not working. I'll post it and I hope you can help me.